# Automation with a Batch File

Tags: batch-file, automation, scheduled-tasks

There is a report going to a location that needs a folder to be there or the report will fail.  So I created a bunch of folders to have them there for a year at a time using a batch file.  That batch file is extremely simple.

```
@echo off

md C:\Users\Joseph\Desktop\TestFolder\2016
md C:\Users\Joseph\Desktop\TestFolder\2016\01-Jan
md C:\Users\Joseph\Desktop\TestFolder\2016\02-Feb
md C:\Users\Joseph\Desktop\TestFolder\2016\03-Mar
md C:\Users\Joseph\Desktop\TestFolder\2016\04-Apr
md C:\Users\Joseph\Desktop\TestFolder\2016\05-May
md C:\Users\Joseph\Desktop\TestFolder\2016\06-Jun
md C:\Users\Joseph\Desktop\TestFolder\2016\07-Jul
md C:\Users\Joseph\Desktop\TestFolder\2016\08-Aug
md C:\Users\Joseph\Desktop\TestFolder\2016\09-Sep
md C:\Users\Joseph\Desktop\TestFolder\2016\10-Oct
md C:\Users\Joseph\Desktop\TestFolder\2016\11-Nov
md C:\Users\Joseph\Desktop\TestFolder\2016\12-Dec
```

This solution was shot down because they don't want the location to have a bunch of empty folders.  So I hid all the folders that were empty and that too shot down and they deleted all my folders.  Now it is a manual process that someone has to remember at 9:00pm CST on the last day of the month to create the folder for the next month.  So I could write a batch file like this.

```
@echo off

md C:\Users\Joseph\Desktop\TestFolder
md C:\Users\Joseph\Desktop\TestFolder\2016\01-Jan
```

and make it a scheduled task and then I just have to change the batch file each month which is a little bit better but it isn't really automated.

Is there a way that I can have the batch file look at the 2016 folder and see what months already exist within it and then have it add the next month unless it is 12-Dec in which case I would want it to create a folder for the following year and fill it with a 01-Jan?

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET /a year=2015
:dloop
SET /a year+=1
FOR %%a IN (01-Jan 02-Feb 03-Mar 04-Apr) DO IF NOT EXIST "%destdir%\%year%\%%a\." MD "%destdir%\%year%\%%a"&GOTO :EOF 
GOTO dloop
```

You would need to change the setting of `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used only Jan..Apr for testing. Obviously, you'd need to complete the set up to `12-Dec`

Simply look for the first directory that does not exist; create it and exit. If you run throughall of the months and they all exist, increment the year and try again.

Or - my preference - let those who mechanically disallow proposed solutions come up with their own scheme.

Comment: This works like a charm.  I will need to dig in to this so that I can make sure to learn why it works but thank you very much this should allow us to completely automate this mundane task out of existence.  I completely agree with your preference because the people that kept shooting me down didn't propose any solutions.  I was able to envision a solution but now thanks to your assistance with the syntax I will be able to make it a reality.  I did click the up vote on this but it said I am not cool enough to display a number yet.